# How to match flexible url using koa-router in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, koa

For example,

`router.get('/files/...', ->)` I want to match `/files/a`, `/files/a/b`, `/files/a/b/c` and so on.

Then, `a`, `a/b`, `a/b/c` will be my handle file path.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for the path, using a regex instead of a string: `/\/files\/(.*)/` -- then the path info should be in `this.params[0]`.

Side note -- if you're using this to serve files directly from the server, make sure to check for a directory traversal attack (often looks like using `..` in the requested path multiple times) so that you don't inadvertently expose other files on the system.